# Using Azure storage on Mac with ASP.NET vNext

Tags: asp.net, macos, azure, mono, asp.net-core

Trying to read data from Azure TableStorage in MVC 6 application on Mac.
It works on PC, but when on Mac it used to give this error:

```
TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.RESTCommand`1[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableResult]' from assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=4.3.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation.ExecuteAsync (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTableClient client, System.String tableName, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableRequestOptions requestOptions, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.OperationContext operationContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>, line 0Stack Query Cookies Headers Environment
TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.RESTCommand`1[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableResult]' from assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=4.3.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation.ExecuteAsync (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTableClient client, System.String tableName, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableRequestOptions requestOptions, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.OperationContext operationContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTableClient.ExecuteAsync (System.String tableName, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation operation, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableRequestOptions requestOptions, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.OperationContext operationContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTable+<>c__DisplayClass4+<<ExistsAsync>b__5>d__0.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[System.Boolean].GetResult () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>
```

After following this [discussion](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/100) and installing `System.Net.Http` package using `kpm` I started to get a new error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Shared.Protocol.HttpClientFactory.BuildHttpClient[TableResult] (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.RESTCommand`1 cmd, System.Net.Http.HttpMessageHandler handler, Boolean useVersionHeader, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.OperationContext operationContext) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>, line 0
```

**Note:
I had the `System.Net.Http` package installed in `"aspnetcore50": { "dependencies": { ... } }`, but it seems like it had to be installed in the common `dependencies`**

Any idea why that might happen and how to fix it?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing about azure storage well as about stackexchange.redis. I think the issue with azure is that it relies on the legacy HttpClient implementation which seems to rely on native win32 apis. There is a new managed implementation in aspnet vnext repository but I don't have figured how to use it right now. I'm afraid we'll have to wait for and updated azure sdk targeting core clr. This is still a very early preview and a lot of things seems to be missing, not working as expected or just undocumented/very hard to understand

Comment: Yes it is a very early build, but still I would like to try to investigate the issue. Who knows, maybe someone has figured out how to bypass it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Azure Storage .NET client under `aspnetcore50`, it's not available for this runtime. You need to pull it under `aspnet50` (`dnx451` now).